# Counting up minutes and hours of a day, adding leading zero to min and hour when single digit - Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, nested-loops

I would like to count all hour minute possibilities of a day in the 24h format xx:xx (needs to be in String)

However I am struggling with getting the leading zeros:

Here is what I have so far:

```
24.times { |h| 60.times { |m| puts "#{h}:#{m}" } }
```

Gives

```
0:0
0:1
...
0:10
...
1:1
...
10:1
...
23:59
```

I would like to have leading zeros on both hour and min

```
00:00  
...
23:59
```

Can it be done in that one line or do I need to split these loops apart?

Comment: is there a reason you're doing this as strings instead of a Time obj?

Comment: Yes there is a reason ...

Comment: @mahatmanich What's the reason? It's always important to know your constraints.

Comment: In future you should consider waiting longer before selecting an answer. Quick-draw selections may discourage other, possibly better, possibly just different, solutions, and imo is discourteous to those still preparing answers.  Sometime--not here--the selected answer is shown to be incorrect. The point is there's no rush. Many here wait at least a couple of hours before awarding the greenie.

Comment: @CarySwoveland never thought about it in that way, but you are right ... removed the greenie ... and waiting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format numbers like that using the syntax: `"0Nd" % i` where `N` is the padding amount (2 in your case) and `i` is the number you want to pad.

```
24.times { |h| 60.times { |m| puts "#{"%02d" % h}:#{"%02d" % m}" } }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(24*60).times { |m| puts "%02d:%02d" % m.divmod(60) }
00:00
00:01
00:02
00:03
00:04
00:05
00:06
00:07
00:08
00:09
00:10
...
23:55
23:56
23:57
23:58
23:59
```

Another way:

```
require 'time'
(24*60).times { |t| puts Time.at(t).strftime("%H:%M") }
```

Comment: That second one is really funky!